# Why can't structs be compared for NULLness in C?

Tags: c, struct, null

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct School
{
    int numOfStudents;
} School;
```

For example if I have a struct:

```
School s;
```

I want to check whether the struct is null like this:

```
if(s) {
    printf("null");
}
```

This will not compile and error message is as follows:

`error: used struct type value where scalar is required`

Why can't I check structs for NULLness inside if statement in C?

Comment: You cannot compare something that is not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: What does `if (s)` mean to you? What *exactly* is tested?

Comment: Because in C `struct` is a [value type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type_and_reference_type).

Comment: You'll need C++ and operator overloading if you want to do this.

Comment: Do you mean something similar to `NULL` or more like `true`/`false`? For usage in a condition (`if(s)`) you need some boolean value. What would make a struct being more true than others for you?

Comment: The real question is indeed what you hoped to achieve by comparing a struct with NULL. To see if it was initialized, or what? That's not what NULL is for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of:

`School s;`

`s` is definitely not NULL, because it is not a pointer.  It is however, an **uninitialized** instance of a struct, and the value of `s.numOfStudents` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` applies to pointer types, and `s` isn't a pointer, it's an *instance* of the `School` type.

If you declared `s` as a *pointer to* `School`, such as

```
School *s;
```

then the null check would make sense:

```
if ( s )
{
  // s points to a valid instance of School
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `null` applies to pointers and `s` is not a pointer.

BTW, `s` is an automatic object that lives on the stack and cannot be null.

Comment: BTW, if s was a global variable, it could not be null either.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes of course. In that case they would live in the data section.

Comment: The fact that `s`  is not a pointer is unrelated to where it lives.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is a special pointer value that is defined to not point anywhere.  You can't check if `s` is `NULL` because `s` is not a pointer.

If your intent is to see if `s` has been *initialized*, you can't do that either because there's no special value that tells you that a variable has been initialized.  For example a uninitialized `int` could contain 0, 1, 34634, -265356657, or any other value.

Your best bet is to initialize the variable with a known value and check for that.

```
School s = { -1 };

if (s.numOfStudents == -1) {
    printf("not used yet\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct consists of data elements. Each element can be null (if appropriate for the type of element), but the struct itself cannot be [compared to] null, even if it has only one data element.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is used only by pointers. For example something like `school *s == NULL` would be valid since `s` is a pointer to type `school`. However in your case `s` is not a pointer therefore it cannot be compared to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

People perform `NULL` checks on pointers to determine *whether or not the pointer is valid*. We would need to call a function to determine whether or not a `struct` was valid, and the answer would depend on knowledge of the exact contents and their meaning. For example...

```
typedef struct
{
    int numOfStudents;
} School;

int null_check(School* item)
{
    /* This test assumes that a School is invalid if it has no students.*/
    return (!item || !item->numOfStudents);
}

/*...*/
School s;
/*...*/
if(null_check(&s)) {
    printf("null");
}
```

**Note** that while a pointer is either pointing at something or not, the question of whether a data structure is valid is potentially much more complex, and should not be confused with the question of whether the structure has been initialized or has every data member set to zero.

Comment: Your null_check works on your own example simply becase you've declared `s` as a global variable.  If `s` was a local variable, declared inside a function, it wouldn't necessarily be zero-initialized.  Especially on a non-debug build.

Comment: Let me clarify that.